# GCC, weird integer promotion scheme

Tags: gcc, integer-promotion

I'm working with GCC v4.4.5 and I've notived a default integer promotion scheme I didn't expected.

To activate enough warnings to prevent implicit bugs I activated the option -Wconversion and since then I've notice that when I perform the code below, the warning *"conversion to ‘short int’ from ‘int’ may alter its value"* is present.

```
signed short sA, sB=1, sC=2;
sA = sB + sC;
```

This means that *"sB + sC"* is promoted to *int* and then assigned to *sA* which is *signed short*.
To fix this warning I have to cast it like this.

```
signed short sA, sB=1, sC=2;
sA = ( signed short )( sB + sC );
```

This warning is also present with the code below.

```
signed short sA=2;
sA += 5;
```

And can be fixed by removing the operator *+=* by this...

```
sA = ( signed short )( sA + 1 );
```

which is a bit annoying cause I can't use the operators *+=*, *-=*.

I expected GCC to select the right integer promotion according to the operands. I mean, *sA=sB+sC* and *sA+=5* should not be promoted to *int* as they all are *signed short*.

I understand that promoting to *int* by default prevents overflow bugs but it's a bit annoying cause I have to cast most of my code or change my variables to *int*.

Is there a GCC option I could use to present this integer promotion scheme ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't have a solution, but you can always write `short` instead of `signed short` in full, which may make this slightly less annoying. I admit it's still annoying though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't gcc, this is standard C semantics.

Per 6.3.1.1:2, *an object or expression with an integer type whose integer conversion rank is less
than or equal to the rank of int and unsigned int* is converted to `int` or `unsigned int` depending on the signedness of the type, prior to participating in arithmetic expressions.

The reason C behaves this way is to allow for platforms where ALU operations on sub-`int` types are less efficient than those on full `int` types.  You should perform all your arithmetic on `int` values, and convert back to `short` only for storage.

Comment: I used to work with Borland C++ and VIsual C++ a few years ago and I was able to use the operator += without any warning. I know GCC strictly supports C rules but I've never seen that before. It's annoying. Thanks for your reply.